# inline-table not working properly on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup box with some contents and used CSS property `display:inline-table;` to auto height popup box as per the content. It is working on Chrome, but not working on IE (In IE it is on the left side). Any other way to manage box height with the proper height?

Code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.alert {
  width: 440px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-table;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #31a3dd;
  border-top: 3px solid #31a3dd;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f7ff;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/f4xn134v/

Comment: IE version is....

Comment: IE 11 & below versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to change the way you are centering the alert to the below. This should center the alert horizontally and vertically.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.alert {
  width: 440px;
  height:auto;
  display:inline-table;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #31a3dd;
  border-top: 3px solid #31a3dd;
  margin: auto auto auto -220px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f7ff;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: J. Spiteri, I have changed only top position for alert class, added my answer

Answer (score 1):

I just removed `display: inline-table` from .alert class and
changed: `top: 30%; bottom: auto;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.alert {
  width: 440px;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #31a3dd;
  border-top: 3px solid #31a3dd;
  margin: auto;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f7ff;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```